# Breakpoint will not be hit on VS2017

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to debug with Visual studio 2017 and Unity 2019.2.0f1.
When pushing the Attach to Unity and Run button, the unity starts playing but my vs breakpoints are showing "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unable to find a corresponding location".

None of the following solutions worked for me:

- Delete .meta files
- Change player settings to .Net4 and then back to .Net2
- Close and reopen both vs2017 and unity
- Delete the whole Library folder

Comment: Did you try deleting the library folder?

Comment: @DeekshithHegde Yes, tried that too

Comment: Have you gone to debug and delete all breakpoints and then readd the breakpoint

Comment: any chance your build is in release mode? not debug

Comment: Are you trying to put breakpoints in partial classes?

Comment: Tried deleting all breakpoints and made sure i'm in debug mode. @Camile it's not a partial class.

Comment: I accidentally put this as an answer before, but did you fix this? I have this isue in 2021.2f1 right now.